# Consume octet-stream data from azure eventhub using node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, azure, azure-eventhub

Iam a beginner in Microsoft event hub. I am successfully reading sample string data from eventHub using node js consumer. but i need to consume octet-stream data. this is my code

```
var messageHandler = function (myIdx, msg) {
console.log("############# Inside Message Handler #######");
console.log(msg.body);
}
```

i dont get the correct data.
But am successfully read data from a txt file. this is my code

```
fs.readFile('/home/test/19_6.txt',  function (err, data) {
console.log(data);
}
```

what i do? any idea ????

this is my octet-stream data [Click here to view](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9izFCDJIZTpWnY1d05xaTJhSEk&usp=sharing)

Comment: What are you doing in MS EventHub? What is the octet-stream data, file or others?

Comment: when i read from a file the data is treated as object or byte array . same data recived from event hub is as String (message.body). I would like to know how to interpret the data from event hub similar to how it was read from a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my experience, you can read a file as byte array and use Base64 encoding to convert it to a string, and then send the Base64 string to EventHub. When you receive the data, you can decode the Base64 string to a byte array.

But I don't recommend this way, because of some limits in EventHub.

Firstly, Maximum size of Event Hubs event is 256KB. Message that exceed this quota will be rejected and an exception will be received by the calling code. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-quotas/.

[image]

Secondly, you need to use some C# APIs such as Event Processor Host API to receive messages from Event Hubs. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-programming-guide/#event-consumers. If you want to use NodeJS to do it, it will be difficult though Event Hub/Service Bus support AMQP protocol.

So I think that you would like to know how to send files to a queue and receive them to do some process. I recommend you to use Azure Storage Queue to implement your idea.

About use Storage Queue from NodeJS, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/ and http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/#toc7.